# Overwriting existing records

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am running into the following scenario with EF Core. It's a API Web application with a few endpoints. For one of them, in the POST method I am getting the following request:

```
ParentObject
{
    "Id": 1111,
    "date": "2019-09-12",
    "message": "This is a fake message",
    "childObject": [
        {
        "Id": 1111,
        "date": "2019-09-12",
        "studentId": "2052",
        "quantity": 25,
        },
        {
        "Id": 1111,
        "date": "2019-09-12",
        "studentId": "2054",
        "quantity": 30,
        }
    ]
}
```

That request is received without any problem and go all the way down to the repository class where the EF core is. Before going to the code, just to give you some context of the functionality. The idea is that on the childObjects we are passing ONLY those objects we detect needs to be inserted and/or modified. For example, in the above request the first child object already exist and we only modified the quantity value. The second child object is a new one.

Currently, that is working OK. EF Core is detecting those changes and doing the appropriate actions on SQL. This is the code:

```
public void Update(MyObject newObject, MyObject exisitingObject)
{
    try
    {
        //Some code for the fields on Parent Object
        ...


        //Code for the child object
        //EF is smart enough to detect if it's a insert or update based on the PKs
        exisitingObject.childObject = newObject.childObject;
        DbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception($"Error attemting to update existing record. {ex.Message}", ex.InnerException);
    }
}
```

As mention before that code is working fine. What is the problem?

Let say I passed the following request:

```
ParentObject
    {
        "Id": 1111,
        "date": "2019-09-12",
        "message": "This is a fake message",
        "childObject": [
            {
            "Id": 1111,
            "date": "2019-09-25",
            "studentId": "3000",
            "quantity": 25,
            }
        ]
    }
```

Same Parent object, new child one. Well the code in EF Core is taking those values and overriding the existing two records on the DB.

Should not EF Core detect that the new child object is a new record based on the PKs and only perform the insert without removing the existing ones?

Any help/ clue is very welcome.

Comment: Why not do a select on dbContext.ParentObject where p.Id == newObject.Id. Check if it's null or not. If null, do a dbContext.ParentObject.Add(newObject), SaveChanges(). If not null, update the properties of ParentObject. Do the same for the child objects, check using LINQ if the child object exists using it's Id, and if not, add it to the ParentObject.children, otherwise update the existing one. Honestly if you structure the code this way it will be more readable and maintainable and will be less bug prone.

Comment: /\ Pretty much what @Jon said.  I would just add that it sounds like you are relying too heavily on EF to do your logic for you, which is never a good idea.

Comment: So you are replacing the existing object collection of child objects (presumable loaded from database?) with another collection containing just one child object? This sounds like equivalent of `Clear`-ing the existing collection (i.e. request to delete all existing child items from the database) and adding one new child object (request to create it in the database). I doubt that this even works for the first scenario. Please provide [mre] and EF Core version in order to see what's going on.

Comment: sorry for the late response. I have the same thought as you mentioned to check if it's null or not (it's already implemented now). Just curious about how EF Core was working under the hood. As Ivan mentioned EF is replacing existing collection of child objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check id  your database for existing childObject

```
var x = db.childobjects.Where(c => c.ID == cildobject.ID).FirstOrDeafult();
If (x != null) {
// then make changes to existing (variable x)
}

else {
db.cildobjects.Add(childobject)
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks David. It's implemented now

Answer (score 0):

```
     using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
        {
            var child = await _dbContext.childObject.FindAsync(child.Id);

            if (child != null)
            {
                _dbContext.Add(child);
            }
            else
            {
                _dbContext.Entry(child).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            transaction.Complete();
        }
```